# UI-Grid exporter - exporting two separate headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, ui-grid, pdfmake

Within AngularJS using pdfmake, I was able to export a header as a pdf.
Using exporterPdfHeader.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.gridOptions.exporterPdfHeader = {

        margin: [30, 5, 30, 10],

        table: {    
            widths: [ '*', '*', '*' ],

            body: [

              [ 'Region: ' + $scope.region, 'Group: ' + $scope.group, 'MC: ' + $scope.mc /*, 'The last one'*/ ],
              [ 'District #: ' + $scope.district, 'Route #: ' + $scope.route, 'Week Ending Date: ' + $scope.weekEndDate, /*, 'Value 4' */],    


            ]


          }

    };
```

Now what I want to do is export ANOTHER header with an image inside of it.  I cannot do both within this one header.  Is there a way I can exporter another separate header?  Or create the image inside this header as a separate row?  Maybe creating another gridOptions? (gridOptions2).  Any assistance would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within columns I was able to create different headers when you export a ui-grid.

```
$scope.gridOptions.exporterPdfHeader = {        
            columns: [
                {           
                margin: [206, 0, 0, 0],

                image: //long url,
                width: 200,
                height: 58,                 
                },
                {
                margin: [ -160, 60, 33, 0 ],

                table: {                        
                    widths: [ '*', '*', '*' ],

                    body: [

                      [ ],   
                    ]           

                  }

                }
             ]               
    };
```